# Sharing Jupyter cells

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have finally began using a jupyter notebook in addition to pycharm. However, I am finding it much more of a hassle to paste code onto stackoverflow from jupyter.

I have the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-9346139ce50d> in <module>
      1 blurred = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
----> 2 grey_blur = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      3 thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(grey_blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 5)
      4 combined = cv2.bitwise_and(new_image, new_image, mask=thresh)
      5 cv2.imshow("cartoon Lau blk shrt", combined)

error: OpenCV(4.5.3) c:\users\runneradmin\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-c2l3r8zm\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xb6623f80::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xb6623f80::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1
```

I want to post the entire code in addition to the error message, but I don't want to go through and crtl+c, crtl+v for each cell, it seems excessive

I want to respect everyone's time here on stackoverflow and am asking for help with understanding best practices.

1-I have heard that running jupyter from VS Code is an option but have not attempted it yet.

2-Is there a way to share directly from jupyter itself or should I look into VS code?

3- maybe there is another option to share a link to the whole project

---

I have attempted downloading a .py file. I was able to drag it into PyCharm but the format was still off

```
# In[ ]:


image = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\holli\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\python photos\\lau black short changing room, haair.jpg')
image.shape


# In[ ]:


x,y,z= image.shape


# In[ ]:


plt.imshow(image)
```

So, at this point I am going to just stick with PyCharm for now.

Comment: You can try downloading jupyter notebook (under "File" tab of your menu bar of jupyter notebook )to a location and try running  it using pycharm ,and display code and error at once. I hope , I answered your question

Comment: @PuneethGP if this is an answer, you should post it as such, not as comment.

Comment: Jesse, sounds like you simply should not be writing jupyter notebooks for the things you do right now - pycharm works really well, doesn't it? The coolness of notebooks is that once you're done with development, you can quickly put things that work into a nice graphical format. The debugging with notebooks really stinks.

Comment: I have been following along with tutorials online, I have between switching back and forth and using the same method as the tutor.  Thank you so much for your clarification.

Comment: SO, Marcus, the reason that I prefer using jupyter is because I am learning tensorflow to use with openCV projects. I like to use the GPUs they provide.   So, how do people using google colab and tensorflow ask questions to stackoverflow? There must be some way. Maybe I can tag tensorflow here, maybe someone that has experience can see it,

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sry brother , I am new here . I learning and getting better at using Stackoverflow . I will post for sure from next time

Comment: @JesseHolliday Colab isn't any different. You just take develop your Python code in pycharms, and make sure you segment it into useful functions. You then `import` that python file with these functions in your notebook, and call these functions. Never try to debug in notebooks, it's just not the thing they're good for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on a cell to select it.
2. Shift+Click on another cell to select that cell and *all* cells in-between.
3. Press just `C` to copy the cell inputs (it's a jupyter shortcut). This should work for copying into other notebooks, *but* you can *also* paste that into any other editor, or a Stack Overflow post.

I don't know of a particular way to copy cell output. It's all text in a web browser so the regular methods for that will work though.